# formatting and use of dictionaries in jinja2 templates

Tags: python, jinja2, boilerplate

I'm trying to add dictionaries `form_label` and `form_field` to this macro call, and it's not going so well.

From the template. Only the macros line is really pertinent to the question.
Let me repeat.  **Only the macros line is really pertinent to the question.**

```
{% block content %}
<div id="edit_profile" class="well-lg">
  <fieldset>
    <form id="form_edit_profile" class="form-horizontal" action="{{ url|safe }}" method="post">
       <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
       {{ macros.field(form.username, label=_("Username"), form_label={class:"col-xs-2"}, form_field={'placeholder':_("Enter your")+" "+_("Username"), class:"form-control focused required"}) }}
       ...
```

and the macro to support it.  (has been updated because I didn't pass class as a string the first time.)

```
{% macro field(field, label='', form_label={},form_field={}) -%}
        <div class="form-group{% if field.errors %} error{% endif %}">
            {% set text = label or field.label.text %}

            {% if field.flags.required %}
                    {{ field.label(text=text + " *", class='control-label '+form_label['class'])}}
            {% else %}
                    {{ field.label(text=text + " ", class='control-label '+form_label['class']) }}
            {% endif %}
            <div class='col-xs-5'>
            {{ field(label, **form_field) }}
            {% if field.errors %}
                {% for error in field.errors %}
                   <label for="{{ field.id }}" class="error help-inline">{{ error }}</label>
                {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
            </div>
        </div>
{%- endmacro %}
```

I'm wondering if I'm referencing the variables incorrectly or if the dictionary keys should be strings or something I'm not considering.

updated the traceback.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1535, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1529, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "/Users/me/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/project/bp_includes/lib/basehandler.py", line 89, in dispatch
    webapp2.RequestHandler.dispatch(self)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/me/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/project/bp_includes/handlers.py", line 112, in get
    return self.render_template('login.html', **params)
  File "/Users/me/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/project/bp_includes/lib/basehandler.py", line 325, in render_template
    self.response.write(self.jinja2.render_template(filename, **kwargs))
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2_extras/jinja2.py", line 158, in render_template
    return self.environment.get_template(_filename).render(**context)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/jinja2-2.6/jinja2/environment.py", line 894, in render
    return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
  File "bp_content/themes/default/templates/login.html", line 1, in top-level template code
    {% extends base_layout %}
TypeError: macro 'field' takes no keyword argument 'placeholder'
```

Comment: l_class doesn't seem to be referenced in any of the posted code. Could you post a more complete traceback?

Comment: I have added the changes.

Comment: The class vs. "class" problem was the only visible problem in the code I pasted which is why the award was given. The problem was from the "{% extends base_layout%}" line which was a container template which also contained another few form field values in another referenced template which I hadn't changed the function profile for and was throwing the errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to reference a variable from a dictionary without the enclosing string:

```
  form_label['class']
```

perhaps that is what is doing it? Also,

```
  form_label = {'class': ''}
```

**Including Comments**:

You have defined the macro as "field" but a variable within it is also labled "field." This could be confusing the parser.

Comment: Ok I changed the class's to "class"'s.  and I'm getting different errors which is a plus.  I'm getting "TypeError: macro 'field' takes no keyword argument 'placeholder'"  Which should be referenced by **form_field shouldn't it?

Comment: You know you've got a recursive definition in there as well. The macro is named "field" but one of the parameters is also named "field."

Answer (score 1):

That is common issue when using dictionary literals in Python.

```
my_dict = {
  key: value
}
```

Require you to have variables named `key` and `value` defined, so in fact

```
key = 1
value = 0

my_dict = {
 key: value
}
```

Will create your dictionary, the same as:

```
my_dict = {
  1 : 0
}
```

So if you wanted to have dictionary where entry key is `'key'` you have to quote it

```
my_dict = {
 'key': 'value'
}
```

Jinja2 templates are no different:

```
 {% macro field(field, label='', form_label={class:""},form_field={class:""}) -%}
```

There are two issues here:

- This requires `class` to be defined
- identifier `field` is used twice

Replace it with:

```
{% macro field_macro(field, label='', form_label={'class':""},form_field={'class':""}) -%}
```

And of course:

```
 {{ field_macro(form.username, label=_("Username"), form_label={'class':"col-xs-2"}, 
        form_field={'placeholder':_("Enter your")+" "+_("Username"), 
            'class':"form-control focused required"}) }}
```

Another gotcha here, are default function parameters.

If by any chance you will change form_field within macro (you can do it in jinja) when default paramter was used ( ie nothing was passed for that parameter), all other calls with no parameter will use changed value.